# How to make sure that profile detail api is not called again for optimization purposes

Tags: angular

Currently I am getting the profile detail using resolver service

Auth service

```
getUserProfile() {
    return this.http.get(this.userProfileApi);
  }
```

Profile detail resolver service

```
export class ProfileDetailsResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
      if(localStorage.getItem('access_token')){
      return this.auth.getUserProfile()
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          if(err.status === 401) {
          localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
          location.reload();
          return throwError(err);
          }
      })
      )
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is use a separate service for profile details so that it is not called again and again on every route change.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

 @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

 export class ProfileDetailsService {

 private subject = new Subject<Details>();

 sendDetails(currentDetails: Details) {
    this.subject.next(currentDetails);
 }


 getDetails(): Observable<Details> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
 }
}
```

How do I change the profile detail resolver service to make the http request and assign the profile details inside the profile details service file.

In the ProfileDetailsResolverService

```
export class ProfileDetailsResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
      isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthService) { }

      resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
          if(localStorage.getItem('access_token')){
          return this.auth.getUserProfile()
          .pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
              if(err.status === 401) {
              localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
              location.reload();
              return throwError(err);
              }
          })
          )
        }
      }
    }
```

And finally subscribe to it wherever you want to have these data :

```
this.profileDetailsService.getDetails().subscribe(currentDetails => {
this.details= currentDetails;
});
```

Comment: Use a `ReplaySubject` instead, so you just need to set value once.