# loading on http request doesn't happen if route resolver service is of type void

Tags: angular, rxjs

Profile detail resolver service of type void

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): void {
      if(localStorage.getItem('access_token')){
      this.auth.getUserProfile().subscribe((res)=>{
          this.profileDetailService.sendDetails(res);
        });
```

Profile Detail service

```
export class ProfileDetailService {
  constructor() { }

  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  sendDetails(currentDetails: any) {
   this.subject.next(currentDetails);
   console.log(currentDetails)
 }

 getDetails(): Observable<any> {
  return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

My dashboard component

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
ngOnInit() {

    this.profileDetailService.getDetails().subscribe((res)=>{
      this.userDetail = res.data;
      this.avatarUrl = this.data.siteLink()+this.userDetail.avatar;
      console.log(this.userDetail);
    });
  }
}
```

The above code works the user details are printed in the console from dashboard component as well as profile detail service component but the loader stops before the http request meaning that the loader doesn't show while the http request to get profile detail is being made.

In the below code the profile detail is printed in the console from profile detail resolver service, profile detail service but the code in dashboard component which getDetail method is called never gets called. In this case the loader shows while http request to get profile detail is being made.

Profile detail resolver

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
      if(localStorage.getItem('access_token')){
      return this.auth.getUserProfile().pipe(

        map((res: any) => {
          this.profileDetailService.sendDetails(res);
          console.log(res);
        })

      );
    }
```

Profile detail service is the same as in case 1.

Dashboard component code is also the same as in case 1.

Below is the app component code which determines the loading now it works for all the other http calls in whatever component they may be but not in case of case 1

```
this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event)=>{
      if(routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.loadingService.setLoading(true);
        this.loadingService.loading$.subscribe((res: boolean)=>{
          this.loading = res;
        })
      }
      if(routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd || 
         routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel || 
         routerEvent instanceof NavigationError){
          this.loadingService.setLoading(false);
          this.loadingService.loading$.subscribe((res: boolean)=>{
            this.loading = res;
          })
      }
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn’t have a resolver return void. The point of a resolver is that it subscribed to a returned observable and loads data for you prior to route navigation. That data is then available in route.data if you want a side effect like calling another service function, then use tap()

Comment: `this.profileDetailService.getDetails().subscribe((re)=>{
//it doesnt return any data when i use return in resolver how to handle that
    });`

Comment: You don’t subscribe in the resolver, the resolver handles the subscription. Use tap instead

Answer (score 0):

a resolver with a return type void will resolve right away and not delay navigation. the point of a resolver is that it delays navigation as needed until an observable completes, and it handles the subscribing for you, so you shouldn't subscribe in the resolver. You can still produce a side effect if desired using the `tap` operator:

```
    return this.auth.getUserProfile().pipe(tap(res=>{
      this.profileDetailService.sendDetails(res);
    }));
```

then you will be able to access this resolved data in your route data like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.data.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: Whats the use of sending the data to profile details `this.profileDetailService.sendDetails(res);` when  are getting the data from route resolver instead of profile detail service

Comment: I don't know, but you did it in your code so I showed you how to replicate it while also making the resolver work.

Comment: My aim was to get data from from profile service due to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230740/how-to-make-sure-that-profile-detail-api-is-not-called-again-for-optimization-pu

Comment: i don't see how subscribing in the resolver helps that problem either?